# SQL: store data field choices in application or in separate table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, schema, database-schema

Given the following SQL table:

```
Ticket:
- id (primary)
- state
- created
```

I want to limit the state to a set of predetermined choices, for example open, pending, closed. Should a given state be stored as a single string for each table row, depending on the application to decide which strings (choices) are allowed? Or should the state be a foreign key of a separate table that stores all allowed values, such as:

```
Ticket:
- id (primary)
- state (foreign)
- created

TicketState
- id (primary)
- name
```

The second options seems better but for large tables with a ton of choices it seems the number of these "extra" tables grows rapidly. What's the most common approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would almost always use a Foreign Key into a lookup table. While you can use a `CONSTRAINT` to limit a column (for example, to 'open', 'pending, 'closed') that approach both hides business logic and also makes it more difficult to add additional values if your requirements change.

The cost of `JOIN`ing to a table on an `INT` clustered primary key is very small and I think that trying to avoid this at the cost of an inferior design is a clear case of premature optimization.

Comment: Well said, thank you! I'll go with the foreign key approach.

Answer (score 1):

ONE TABLE: How often you add, remove, or rename TicketState's name? Do you plan to use any database other than MySQL in the future? If not, ENUM is your friend for MySQL.

TWO TABLES: Even if you make TicketState separately, it will not grow as Ticket grows. It will be fixed by the number of possible states. It may require additional join, but it's less risky (RECOMMENDED)

Comment: Also a good argument about using less space with two tables. Thanks!